# Why do I have the feeling my F# code could be more concise

Tags: f#, immutability

I'm an experienced C# developer trying to teach myself F#. I spent a day or 3 reading throught the [F# wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming) trying to get to know the syntax and F# fundamentals.

As an exercise I'm trying to go through the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems to get a better feeling of the syntax and working with the language.

I've just solved [problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5). But I'm not so happy about the hoops I had to jump through to get a data structure that represents my solution.
I've used [this blogpost](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-5/) to get to the algorithm for solving the problem.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers as to how this code could be improved? My guess is that the inherent immutability of F# values is causing me to have to perform a lot of steps to get the exact data I want...

This is my code:

```
let main argv =
//calculates the prime factors of a number
let findPrimeFactors x =
    let primes = [|2I;3I;5I;7I;11I;13I;17I;19I|]
    let rec loop acc counter = function
        | x when x = 1I -> failwith "A PRIME IS BY DEFINITION GREATER THAN 1"
        | x when primes |> Array.contains x -> x :: acc
        | x when counter = primes.Length -> failwith "MY LIST OF KNOWN PRIMES IS NOT BIG ENOUGH"
        | x when x%primes.[counter]=0I-> loop (primes.[counter]::acc) (counter) (x/primes.[counter])
        | x -> loop acc (counter + 1) x

    let primeFactor = loop [] 0 x |> List.rev
    primeFactor

//calculates the prime factors for each of the numbers between 2 and n
//then, for each of the prime factorizations it tries to find the highest power for each occurring prime factor
let findPrimeFactorsPowers n =
    //builds a map of all the prime factor powers for all prime factorizations
    let rec addCounterFactorPowers factorPowers = function
        | counter when counter = n -> factorPowers
        | (counter : int) -> addCounterFactorPowers ((findPrimeFactors (counter|>bigint) |> List.countBy (fun x-> x)) @ factorPowers) (counter + 1)
    let allFactorPowers = addCounterFactorPowers [] 2
    //group all the powers per prime factor
    let groupedFactorPowers = allFactorPowers |> List.groupBy (fun (factor, power) -> factor)
    //get the highest power per prime factor
    let maxFactorPowers = groupedFactorPowers |> List.map (fun (key, powers) -> (key, powers |> List.map (fun (factor, power) -> power) |> List.max))

    //return the result
    maxFactorPowers        

let n = 20; 
let primeFactorSet = findPrimeFactorsPowers n
printfn "%A" primeFactorSet

let smallestNumberDivisableByAllNumbersBelown =  (primeFactorSet |> List.fold (fun state (factor, power) -> state * pown factor power) 1I)
printfn "Result %A" smallestNumberDivisableByAllNumbersBelown

System.Console.ReadKey(true)|>ignore
0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: If your code functions 100% correctly (and your question meets all the requirements at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ), I would consider posting this question to the CodeReview stackexchange instead.  This kind of question seems like it would be more suited there.

Comment: Remove comments for instant 20% reduction. :)

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Ok, was hesitant to post the question on code review as I was looking for more general ways to work around the immutability in F#. And I was expecting more reaction here. But I posted it on Code review now. Closing it here

Comment: If you want to avoid immutability, why are you using a functional language @Stif?

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn myself F#. It's just an exercise as a means to get to know the language better. I had the impression my code could be more concise, but with my limited knowledge at this point in time I thought some other people might be able to give some pointers as to how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

There are many direct simplifications you can apply to your code, but I don't think that's the best approach.

This is the way I would solve that problem in F#:

```
let rec tryDivide n m =
    if m = 1 then true
    else
        if n % m = 0 then tryDivide n (m-1)
        else false

let rec findIt i m =
    if tryDivide i m then i
    else findIt (i+1) m

findIt 1 20
```

It's a bit slower than yours because it doesn't use hardcoded primes, they're calculated on the fly, but still it takes less than 2 secs on my computer to get the right answer.

Note that I'm not using any list-like data structure and no need to rely on big integers in this specific problem.

**UPDATE**

Here's a better approach based on Kvb's proposed solution:

```
let rec gcd x y = if y = 0 then abs x else gcd y (x % y)

let lcm a b = 
    match (a, b) with
    | (_, 0) | (0, _) ->  0
    | (x, y) -> abs ((x / (gcd x y)) * y)

Seq.fold lcm 1 {2..20}
```

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. That is indeed the easier brute force way. Since my goal is learning F#, I wanted to challenge myself into coding the actual algorithm more than coming up with a quick solution.

Comment: But looking for complex solution for simple problems takes you to a dark zone where it's not easy to advise, since you realise all the time you're over-engineering. I would suggest stick to simple solutions and continue with project Euler, it will get more complicated very soon :)

Comment: Of course, there are also simple but not brute force ways to solve the problem (e.g. `List.fold lcm 1 [2..20]` for a suitably defined `lcm` function that computes the least common multiple of two integers, which returns the correct result effectively instantaneously).

Comment: @kvb I updated the answer with your suggestion. That's actually faster and shorter. Credit should go to you :)